# Show GIF and wait for key press

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to automate the labelization of sequences of images. I need to sort them relative to a certain number, which can be found easily by a human operator.

My idea is to show, for each sequence, a gif (pops up on screen), have the operator press a digit key, and then copy the sequence to the correct location, and pop another gif, etc.

For now, I managed to show gifs, and to wait for button press, but I can't get the exact key that was pressed...

Any idea how to do that ? And I'd like to be able to press the key while having the gif on front, not in the terminal...

Here's my code :

```
    fig = plt.figure()
    for img in sequence:
        im = plt.imshow(img_array,animated=True,cmap='gray')
        ims.append([im])

    ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig,ims,interval=50,blit=True,repeat_delay=1000)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(1)
    n = raw_input("how many?")
    plt.close(fig) ## shows all the gifs at once, opening multiple windows.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to use an animation here, because that would give the user only a fixed, limited time to decide for pressing a key. Instead, use the pressing of a key to trigger the change to the next image.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

images = [np.random.rand(10,10) for i in range(13)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im = ax.imshow(images[0], vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap='gray')

curr = [0]
def next_image(evt=None):
    n = int(evt.key)
    # do something with current image
    print("You pressed {}".format(n))
    # advance to next image
    if curr[0] < len(images)-1:
        curr[0] += 1
        im.set_array(images[curr[0]])
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    else:
        plt.close()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", next_image)        
plt.show()
```

Comment: Works perfectly for single images, but I'd like to see gifs, is that possible ?

Comment: solved this by having a keystroke show the next image of the sequence, and other key strokes to see another sequence. Works fine.